# GATEWAY FUSIONPBX

Tags: sip, gateway, freeswitch, pbx, fusionpbx

I am not that much of a guru in fusionpbx. I have already set it up. I need to add a gateway from a provider that does not have a username and password. The provider only has an IP. My problem is that when i try to add the gateway i get an error message that i must put a username and a password. How to i go about adding the gateway?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The username and password are required by mod_sofia. You can however set the gateway with register set to false. Give it a try if that fails then set extension in contact, and contact in from to true. Then stop and start the gateway. You should see a status of 'noreg'.

Its now ready to use go to Dialplan -> Outbound Routes to select that Gateway and then you can send calls to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "Register" to false, if the provider doesn't have a username & password.

I had to do this with a FXO gateway device.  The gateway and pbx will work in peer mode (non-registered).

For the FXO gateway I needed to set the following settings:

- **Gateway:** `FXO_Gateway_1` (this is just a name)
- Leave these field blank: **Username, Password, From User, From Domain, Proxy, Realm**
- **Register**: `False`
- **Context**: `public`
- **Profile**: `external`
- Leave **Hostname** blank.  I made the mistake of setting this.  It will not work.
- Enabled: **True**
- Click Advanced to set **Outbound Proxy**: `<provider ip:port>`